# Why am I getting the UnboundLocalError that says local variable 'participants' referenced before assignment in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have these lines of code, but I keep getting this error:

**Error**

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'participants' referenced before assignment

Does anybody know what Im doing wrong, this is my code:

**Code:**

```
class Competition(object):
    def __init__(self, place, date, start_place, start_time):
        self.place = place
        self.date = date
        self.start_place = start_place
        self.start_time = start_time
        participants = []

    def registration(self, name):
        self.name = name
        participants += self.name
        return deelnemers

participant1 = Competition('Italy', '2018-05-24', 'Rome', '21:55')
participant1.registration('Tom Dumoulin')
```

Comment: as you know participants are a local variable you assigned an empty list and never used, and also you are returning a variable that is undefined means never assigned

Comment: In the last statement of `registration` you probably also want to return `participants` ..

Comment: Note that you seem to have mixup in your ideas. You have a  Competition class, but you seem to work with participant objects - but you are not, in fact. Also you have a name property and participants property both of competition but one would seem to be a single participant, the other for the whole list of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your `__init__` and `registration` methods, `participants` is a variable that is local to each method.  This means that after the methods finish running, those variable vanish.

If you want to store `participants` as part of the `Competition` class, you can attach it to the instantiated objects using `self`

```
class Competition(object):
    def __init__(self, place, date, start_place, start_time):
        self.place = place
        self.date = date
        self.start_place = start_place
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.participants = []

    def registration(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.participants.append(self.name)
```

Comment: You just want to change += self.name to += [ self.name] probably

Answer (score 1):

You define participants without self prefix in **init** Therefore it is a function local variable that does not exist outside **init** function.

Then you  try to reference it in registration function, but it is not a class variable (no self.  prefix), therefore it isn't  set anymore after init finished and therefore you are trying to add something to non existent variable.

Hence the error.

If you wanted a variable shared among all instances of the class, you define it inside class but outside all class functions and then refer to it by Competition.participants from inside functions.

If you want the variable to be tied to instance of class, then in all cases you use self. prefix - both when setting variable and when referring to it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`participants = []` in `__init__` does nothing useful, because the list is not bound to the instance being initialized. You probably wanted
 `self.participants = []`.

In `registration` you must refer to that list when trying to extend it with `+=`, i.e. `self.participants += ...`.

Note that this will give you either an error if `name` is not iterable or an unexpected result if `name` is a string (each letter will be appended to the list individually). You probably want the list's `append` method here instead of `extend` (which is called when using `+=`).